# NodeJS Stop and Start with Batch

Tags: node.js, batch-file

I am trying to start and stop a nodejs app every `n` minutes on batch. This is what I have so far:

```
node index.js
pause
```

I think the way to do this is to use a `for` loop and wait `n` minutes, then stop the app. The problem is, how do I stop an nodejs app through batch?

I tried:

```
node index.js
sleep 30 //sleeps for 30 seconds
node index.js
sleep 30
```

The problem is, it will never get to sleep 30 seconds because my node js app never ends, therefore it will not go to the next line. Is there anyway to stop the program then continue with batch file.

I am talking about a .bat file.

Comment: Would you mind explaining your need for this? Or better asked, why not simply use `setInterval()` to loop the code in `index.js` every 30 seconds instead of wanting to restart the whole process itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to force re-run all in `index.js`, you can try use `bot.js` (or any name you want) [child_process.exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback):

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const loop = () => exec('node index.js', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
loop();
setInterval(loop, 30000);
```

If you just want run code inside `index.js`, you can use `loop` function is the code you want re-run (because it is long to start with `exec`).

Comment: this works, but pretend I want it to loop every 30 minutes. I think the setInterval only starts after 30 minutes.

Comment: @GemClash simply call `loop()` before the setInterval to start it the first time :p